# Can you pass query params from codesandbox url to inner browser?

Tags: codesandbox

I would like to know if it's possible to have a codesandbox with query params (i.e. `https://codesandbox.io/<some-id>?qp1=val1&qp2=val2`), and to pass the `qp1` and `qp2` query parameters to the inner browser, so that the program that codesandbox is running will receive those params.)

If I just put some query params in the url, they are not received in the inner process.

Couldn't figure it out neither from their documentation, nor from this or other forums.